# What's the appropriate procedure for dealing with team killers in War Thunder?

Tags: war-thunder

Last night, I was playing War Thunder (Ground forces - with tanks =D). I made a sub-optimal move, and after that I spent most of the match getting team killed by one guy (3 times in total).

**What's the appropriate procedure for dealing with team killers in War Thunder?** What will happen to them? In a similar game, World of Tanks, there's an automated system that tracks and records team damage/kills, and if you are too abusive towards your team, you get hit with an auto ban. Before that, the player name will turn blue. This system in World of Tanks kicks in pretty quick - a player's name will turn blue after only 2 team kills in a row, even on a clean account. Additionally, the teamkiller will be hit with severe XP and credit penalties. Yet, in War Thunder, they didn't place last on the scoreboard and as far as I know, didn't seem to get hit with any penalties.

---

**Situation**

I'm playing Rank I tanks. I'm really new at War Thunder and don't know all the controls yet (like hooking up a rope to tow a tank). Near a capture point, I see an enemy tank and hit the brakes so I can take aim. My soon-to-be teamkiller drives into my rear. My bad, I guess.

He keeps pushing and somehow flips my tank sideways (so that the top of my turret is now facing the enemy, my left track is the only thing touching the ground, and my underside is showing to the tank behind me, owned by the soon-to-be teamkiller. The physics of the game are a bit strange here and there, but oh well. I hit the rope key, which spawn a tow icon above my head. My soon-to-be-teamkiller has a tow icon too. When I mouse over his tank, a rope appears between his and my tank. I click, hoping this attaches the rope. The main gun fires instead. The shell flies off to somewhere, since my turret is aiming at the sky.

My soon-to-be-teamkiller becomes a teamkiller as he firmly plants an AP shell in the bottom of my tank. Perhaps I was in the way, perhaps uprighting me takes too long. I don't really care, I have tons of lives left. I'm slightly frustrated and type "Flipper and teamkiller, GJ" in team chat. No response.

In my new tank, I start driving towards the capture point again. A good 30 seconds later, I'm taking shots on my... rear? My suspension gets damaged. It's the same guy! He's shooting at me, deliberately. I ignore it. More shots hit my rear. I move to the side, his turret follows me. He shoots off my track. I'm pissed, and start firing back. My shells do little; they bounce off his front plate. I put a dent in his horizontal turret traverse. He places a shell through my drivers hatch, which, after a bounce on some steel plate in my tank, explodes and kills all my crew. Next tank.

I write "How to report a teamkiller?" in all chat. No responses yet. My new tank has artillery support, I drive towards the front line with the plan of dumping artillery support on the capture point so that we maybe might win. This game is very even right now. If I could help, maybe we could win!

The teamkiller comes driving back and starts putting shots in my front. I dump artillery on him and keep driving. The artillery misses him, and I end up dead by having my engine blown up via teamkiller-shell to the rear.

Someone says that I can report a teamkiller via TAB to show the player scoreboard, then right click their name. It brings up a menu, add to friends, add to blacklist, view playercard, complain... I select complain and file a report.

After the match is over, I see he's placed 13th of 15 players on our team. I'm placed 10th, having managed to kill something in the early parts of the game. He doesn't seem to be penalized in any way. I add the player to my blacklist, despite not knowing what that does. I hope it's an ignore feature.

---

Are there things I did wrong, both in gameplay (you always check behind you before braking!) and in policy (don't ever shoot teammates, even if they shoot you!)? What can I do to deal with team killers? Will I get penalized for leaving the match early?

Comment: About your story, I'll say you provoked him with your message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did some searching to find out how the automated system in War Thunder works.

I found this page - [Teamkilling - Gaijin](https://gaijin.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/200069301-Teamkilling):

> Any team kill incident has negative consequences for the team-killer. We already have auto-kick and auto-ban features:
>
> **Arcade Battles (AB)**
>
> 3 TK per session - auto kick from session
>   8 TK per day – auto kick from session and 1 day ban
>   17 ТК per week – 7 day ban
>   25 ТК in two weeks – 1 month ban
>   35 TK per month – 2 months ban
>
> **Historical Battles (HB) / Full Real Battles (FRB)**
>
> 2 TK per session – auto kick from session.
>   5 TK per day – auto kick from session and 1 day ban
>   17 ТК per week – 7 day ban
>   25 ТК in 2 weeks– 1 month ban
>   35 TK per month – 2 month ban
>
> **If players teamkill you, they get a penalty (depending on what type of aircraft you're flying).**

It seems that based on this, if you get team-killed enough it will eventually stop. Also, there's a penalty (but the page only says aircraft...?).

> Also, according to our [teamkilling policy](http://forum.warthunder.com/index.php?/topic/129124-team-killing-policy) you can report abusive teamkilling by right-clicking player's name in the game.

I already knew about this, after being told about this in chat.

---

Looking at the numbers, it seems firing back is a bad idea. If I kill the teammate I'm shooting at, I'll have to pay a credit fine. Additionally, doing so risks me getting a ban if I do it often enough.

---

**Regarding Towing**

To attach a rope, mouse over your teammate who has the tow rope icon over their head, and push the "help" button.

Comment: How can you get 35 team kills in one month if you're already banned for a month after 25 of them?

Comment: "karlano" doesn't have enough reputation yet, but he says: "If a player pushes a team member out of bounds, they kill the team member and dont get a teamkill against them. Warthunder lacks proper TK programming. If you blacklist any player, that should prevent you from ever seeing that TK on your team again." Just pasting here, because it's probably meant for you.